# /: Unterminated groupregular expression: /R<f(9f

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, fs

I have 2 very big txt files, file A contains some strings and on file B I have all the strings that i will search on file A.

Actually I turned file B into an array and with fs I loaded file A. The problem is that file B is containing some strange strings like `R<f(9f` so when I do match with regexp, the program exits with the error message `/: Unterminated groupregular expression: /R<f(9f`.
So what I want to do is that the regexp match "treats" the characters as strings and not as instructions.

```
console.time('program');
const fs = require('fs');


const filePath = "./processhackerfile.txt";
const hackStringsPath = "./hackstrings.txt";

var hackStrings = fs.readFileSync(hackStringsPath).toString().split("\n");
console.log(hackStrings.length);
var file = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString();

for(i in hackStrings){

    var regex = new RegExp(hackStrings[i].toString(), 'i');
    var stringSearch = file.match(regex);

    if(stringSearch != null){
        console.log(`Cheat found, string name: ${stringSearch}`);
    } else {
        console.log('Cheat not found');
    }
}


console.timeEnd('program');
```

You can find the code [here](https://pastebin.com/V6YJeh63)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the string to use in regular expression verbatim. Unfortunately there seems to be no built-in method to do that, however there are npm packages available for that, like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-string-regexp

Comment: Unfortunately the package that you gave to me is not working... `ReferenceError: escapeStringRegexp is not defined`

Comment: Have you `require`d it? Works just fine over here.

Still that's just of the packages, there are lots more on npm, and you can choose what's working for you.

Comment: No problem i made myself the func `RegExp.escape = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};`